# SSAS Processing Cubes - Won't work in powershell but works in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, powershell, visual-studio-2012, ssas, ssas-2012

I'm attempting to process cubes and dimensions in powershell. It has been working for awhile but all of a sudden it stops. I can process the dimensions and cubes in visual studio but processing them with a powershell script in the same order gives me a duplicate attribute key error.

Powershell Script:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")


$serverAS = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server

$serverAS.connect("SERVER")



$db = $serverAS.databases["ANALYSIS DB"]

$db.cubes | select name, storagemode, lastprocessed

$db.dimensions | select name, isparentchild, lastprocessed, storagemode

Foreach ($c in $db.dimensions)  {$c.process("ProcessFull")}

Foreach ($c in $db.cubes)  {$c.process("ProcessFull")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I was actually able to get around this by using SSDT and Integration Services to process Dimensions and Cubes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ignore the key errors like this:

```
## Set up the Error Configuration so that Key Errors are ignored
$errorConfig = New-Object `
    Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ErrorConfiguration("D:\ProcessLogs\")
$errorConfig.KeyNotFound = "ReportAndContinue"
$errorConfig.KeyErrorAction = "ConvertToUnknown"
$errorConfig.KeyErrorLimit = -1
```

and then process with this error config parameter:

```
## Process the current database
$c.Process("ProcessFull", $errorConfig)
```

Reference and Example:
http://www.biadmin.com/2012/07/bi-admin-scripts-process-ssas-database.html